# Concatenating key value pairs from a list in R

Tags: sql, r, list

I have a list of objects that I would like to concatenate into a string. This will ultimately be used to construct a SQL statement.

```
library(purrr)
test <- list(key = "value", key1 = "value1", key2 = "value2")

> test
$key
[1] "value"

$key1
[1] "value1"

$key2
[1] "value2"

map2(names(test), test, ~paste(.x, "=", .y)) %>% 
  reduce(c) %>% 
  paste0(collapse = ", ")
```

This gives the desired result, but wondering if I'm missing a more obvious solution.

```
[1] "key = value, key1 = value1, key2 = value2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use paste

You can obtain the same result by only using `paste`:

```
paste(names(test), test, sep = " = ", collapse = ", ")
```

Output:

```
[1] "key = value, key1 = value1, key2 = value2"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I'm on too much coffee right now lol. Thanks a lot. Knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Or we can convert to a `data.frame` and `paste` with `do.call`

```
do.call(paste, c(stack(test)[2:1], sep=" = ", collapse=", "))
#[1] "key = value, key1 = value1, key2 = value2"
```

Comment: That gets the opposite order: value = key, when it should be key = value. What's the advantage of putting it in a data frame, when it seems like the operative part is your `paste` call?

Comment: @camille Regarding the advantage.  It does some checks with `NULL` e.g. `test <- list(key = "value", key1 = NULL, key2 = "value2")`; Now, you can run both the solutions